# invalid date/time string: Sun Jun 03 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time) CFML

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I'm trying to query to database using information from a html input. The format of the date is:

```
    Date {Sun Jun 03 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)}
```

In the database query I used

```
    parseDateTime( arguments.start )
```

.. where `arguments.start` represents the date format shown above. But when I try to run the query, I get the response below from the web page:

> invalid date/time string: Sun Jun 03 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT
>   Daylight Time)

Comment: Afaik GMT doesn't follow DST so "GMT Daylight time" isn't a valid TZ definition, are you sure you don't want BST (British Summer Time)?

Comment: Hi FVU, what do you think i should do

Comment: I'd try to get the datetime info in a standards compliant format, ie with an existing timezone.  Bit you don't say where this string comes from, so it's hard to give you precise advice...

Comment: You could try `new Date().toISOString()` to get an ISO8601 formatted date-time string, but that may be problematic with older browsers.

Comment: didnt work though, realy dont know wat to do @fvu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what format you have there, but that is not a valid ISO 8601 time format. All ISO times formats are always GMT and are one of the following formats:

- 1994-11-05T13:15:30Z
- 1994-11-05T08:15:30-05:00

I would check whatever is giving you that string value.